# asyncio : How to handle empty queue when you use non-blocking get()?

Tags: python, exception, queue, python-asyncio

I want to handle the empty exception

https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Empty

https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.SimpleQueue.get

but in this simplified code there are two errors. It doesn't know `queue.Empty` and `timeout`

```
queue = asyncio.Queue()

while (True):
 try:    
    newItem = await queue.get(timeout = 5)
 except queue.Empty:
    print(f"{bcolors.FAIL}END")
```

> newItem = await queue.get(timeout = 5)
> TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "test.py", line 158, in main
> except queue.Empty:
> AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'Empty'

EDIT:
Thank , but see the simplified code below please

```
async def worker(name):
while True:
    queue_msg = await queue_.get()
        #...Process the messages.....#       

async def main():
try:
    #......#
    cursor = await db.execute("SELECT id FROM title WHERE data=?", ('2021-02-05',))
                #........#
                #Create 5 task messages and process it
                while (cont < 4):
                    #get messages based on id 
                    async for msg in client.messages(id(cont)):
                        #Put message on queque
                        await queue_.put(msg)                    
                        cont = cont + 1

                -> Here I need to verify if queque is empty
```

How Do I know when queue is empty so I can process the next 5 message?
I can't use non-blocking get()

Comment: `asyncio.Queue.get` doesn't take a `timeout` argument, and `queue.Empty` is in the `queue` module, not your `queue` object.

Comment: Also, you only need to handle the `Empty` exception if you use the non-blocking version of `get()`, which you don't.